# How to groupby().transform() to value_counts() in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I am processing a pandas dataframe `df1` with prices of items.

```
  Item    Price  Minimum Most_Common_Price
0 Coffee  1      1       2
1 Coffee  2      1       2
2 Coffee  2      1       2
3 Tea     3      3       4
4 Tea     4      3       4
5 Tea     4      3       4
```

I create `Minimum` using:

```
df1["Minimum"] = df1.groupby(["Item"])['Price'].transform(min)
```

How do I create `Most_Common_Price`?

```
df1["Minimum"] = df1.groupby(["Item"])['Price'].transform(value_counts()) # Doesn't work
```

In the moment, I use a multi-step approach:

```
for item in df1.Item.unique().tolist(): # Pseudocode
 df1 = df1[df1.Price == Item]           # Pseudocode
 df1.Price.value_counts().max()         # Pseudocode
```

which is overkill. There must be a more simple way, ideally in one line

**How to groupby().transform() to value_counts() in pandas?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use `groupby` + `transform` with `value_counts` and `idxmax`.

```
df['Most_Common_Price'] = (
    df.groupby('Item')['Price'].transform(lambda x: x.value_counts().idxmax()))

df

     Item  Price  Minimum  Most_Common_Price
0  Coffee      1        1                  2
1  Coffee      2        1                  2
2  Coffee      2        1                  2
3     Tea      3        3                  4
4     Tea      4        3                  4
5     Tea      4        3                  4
```

---

An improvement involves the use of `pd.Series.map`,

```
# Thanks, Vaishali!
df['Item'] = (df['Item'].map(df.groupby('Item')['Price']
                        .agg(lambda x: x.value_counts().idxmax()))
df

     Item  Price  Minimum  Most_Common_Price
0  Coffee      1        1                  2
1  Coffee      2        1                  2
2  Coffee      2        1                  2
3     Tea      3        3                  4
4     Tea      4        3                  4
5     Tea      4        3                  4
```

Comment: @sudonym notice , this method will also work for the object :-)

Comment: @Wen Thank you, that's an important consideration I didn't think of!

Comment: as you can see in my reputation, I am a rookie. Could you kindly elaborate what you mean with object here?

Comment: @sudonym For example, if `Price` was a column of strings and you wanted to find the string with the highest count per group, this would still work. Whereas `mode` only works for numbers.

Comment: get it - I was confused because a number is an (int or float) object too

Comment: @sudonym `pandas` objects are typed like `numpy`, they can contain either arrays of primitive types, e.g. `numpy.int64`, or, `dtype=object`, in which case, they can contain *any* python object. Note, that usually comes at the expense of efficiency.

Comment: Use map instead of transform and performance improves further. df['Item'].map(df.groupby('Item').Price.agg(lambda x: x.value_counts().idxmax()))

Comment: What if two values have the same occurrences, and in that case, we need to put if-else statement, i.e get the mode only if 1 value has maximum occurrence. If 2 values have same occurrences, go to else statement. How'd we do that.

Comment: I think in the second code block, it should also read: `df['Most_Common_Price'] = (df['Item'].map(df.groupby('Item')['Price']
                        .agg(lambda x: x.value_counts().idxmax()))`

Answer (score 10):

A nice way is to use `pd.Series.mode`, if you want the most common element (i.e. the mode).

```
In [32]: df
Out[32]:
     Item  Price  Minimum
0  Coffee      1        1
1  Coffee      2        1
2  Coffee      2        1
3     Tea      3        3
4     Tea      4        3
5     Tea      4        3

In [33]: df['Most_Common_Price'] = df.groupby(["Item"])['Price'].transform(pd.Series.mode)

In [34]: df
Out[34]:
     Item  Price  Minimum  Most_Common_Price
0  Coffee      1        1                  2
1  Coffee      2        1                  2
2  Coffee      2        1                  2
3     Tea      3        3                  4
4     Tea      4        3                  4
5     Tea      4        3                  4
```

As @Wen noted, `pd.Series.mode` can returns a `pd.Series` of values, so just grab the first:

```
Out[67]:
     Item  Price  Minimum
0  Coffee      1        1
1  Coffee      2        1
2  Coffee      2        1
3     Tea      3        3
4     Tea      4        3
5     Tea      4        3
6     Tea      3        3

In [68]: df[df.Item =='Tea'].Price.mode()
Out[68]:
0    3
1    4
dtype: int64

In [69]: df['Most_Common_Price'] = df.groupby(["Item"])['Price'].transform(lambda S: S.mode()[0])

In [70]: df
Out[70]:
     Item  Price  Minimum  Most_Common_Price
0  Coffee      1        1                  2
1  Coffee      2        1                  2
2  Coffee      2        1                  2
3     Tea      3        3                  3
4     Tea      4        3                  3
5     Tea      4        3                  3
6     Tea      3        3                  3
```

Comment: a minor change `df.groupby(["Item"])['Price'].transform(lambda x : x.mode()[0])`, in case have two same one :-)

Comment: Is it possible that pandas changed the evaluation of your first solution? `df.groupby(["Item"])['Price'].transform(pd.Series.mode)` returns `ValueError: Length of passed values is 1, index implies 3` on my machine.

Comment: @00schneider: that's because the mode in your case applied to two or more values; use BENY's suggestion

Answer (score 0):

```
    #Initial dataframe having Milk as Nan value to produce the scenario if we have any group nan value 
    data_stack_try = [['Coffee',1],['Coffee',2],['Coffee',2],['Tea',3],['Tea',4],['Tea',4],['Milk', np.nan]]
    df_stack_try = pd.DataFrame(data_stack_try, columns=["Item","Price"])
    print("---Before Min---")
    print(df_stack_try)
    #Created Minimum column with transform function with 'min'
    df_stack_try["Minimum"] = df_stack_try.groupby(["Item"])['Price'].transform(min)
    print("---After Min----")
    print(df_stack_try)

    #Function written to take care of null values (Milk item is np.nan)
    def mode_group(grp):
        try:
            #return mode of each group passed for each row
            return grp.mode()[0]
        except BaseException as e:
            # This exception will be raised if there is no mode value 
            # In this case it will appear for Milk value as because of nan, it can't have mode value
            print("Exception!!!")
    df_stack_try["Most_Common_Price"] = df_stack_try.groupby('Item')['Price'].transform(lambda x: mode_group(x))
    print("---After Mode----")
    print(df_stack_try)
```

```
---Before Min---
     Item  Price
0  Coffee    1.0
1  Coffee    2.0
2  Coffee    2.0
3     Tea    3.0
4     Tea    4.0
5     Tea    4.0
6    Milk    NaN
---After Min----
     Item  Price  Minimum
0  Coffee    1.0      1.0
1  Coffee    2.0      1.0
2  Coffee    2.0      1.0
3     Tea    3.0      3.0
4     Tea    4.0      3.0
5     Tea    4.0      3.0
6    Milk    NaN      NaN
Exception!!!
---After Mode----
     Item  Price  Minimum  Most_Common_Price
0  Coffee    1.0      1.0                2.0
1  Coffee    2.0      1.0                2.0
2  Coffee    2.0      1.0                2.0
3     Tea    3.0      3.0                4.0
4     Tea    4.0      3.0                4.0
5     Tea    4.0      3.0                4.0
6    Milk    NaN      NaN                NaN
```

Comment: Please, add text description to the code provided