# Add column to pandas dataframe with values in a column divided by max of column based on group from another column?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
drinks = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/justmarkham/pandas-videos/master/data/drinks.csv') 
drinks.head(3)
```

|  | country | beer_servings | continent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Afghanistan | 0 | Asia |
| 1 | Albania | 89 | Europe |
| 2 | Algeria | 25 | Africa |

```
drinks.shape()
(193, 6) 
drinks.groupby('continent')['beer_servings'].max() 

continent
Africa           376
Asia             247
Europe           361
North America    285
Oceania          306
South America    333
Name: beer_servings, dtype: int64
```

What I want to do is take the beer_servings column, and, for each country, look up which continent it is in, look up the max of the beer_servings column **for that specific continent**, and then divide the beer_servings entry by the max of that column (but only for whichever continent that country happens to be in), and append a new column to my original dataframe with these "normalized" values. How can I do that? And, can you explain the code? What is a good idiomatic way to do this in Pandas?

Thanks!

Comment: can you share expected output please? I think i got what you want as output but want to see the output before i send you the results

Comment: you can do a transform and store the max value for each row. Then divide the beer serving with the max value column

Comment: What have you tried so far E.J.? What issue are you having with what you've tried?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to groupby().transform() to value\_counts() in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47898768/how-to-groupby-transform-to-value-counts-in-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

You could write a code as you explained. First, you can create a dictionary having continent names as keys with values of the maximum beer servings for each continent. Then apply dict.get function for each `row["beer_servings"]` and `row["continent"]` as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pd.options.display.max_columns = None
    pd.options.display.max_rows = None
    pd.options.display.width = None
    drinks = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/justmarkham/pandas-videos/master/data/drinks.csv")
    drink_max_dict = drinks.groupby("continent")["beer_servings"].max().to_dict()
    print(f"[main] max of drink: {drink_max_dict}")
    drinks["norm_beer_servings"] = drinks.apply(lambda row: row["beer_servings"] / drink_max_dict.get(row["continent"], 0), axis=1)
    print(drinks.head(3))
```

Result:

```
[main] max_drink: {'Africa': 376, 'Asia': 247, 'Europe': 361, 'North America': 285, 'Oceania': 306, 'South America': 333}
       country  beer_servings  spirit_servings  wine_servings  total_litres_of_pure_alcohol continent  norm_beer_servings
0  Afghanistan              0                0              0                           0.0      Asia            0.000000
1      Albania             89              132             54                           4.9    Europe            0.246537
2      Algeria             25                0             14                           0.7    Africa            0.066489
```

Comment: You don't need to convert it to dict and load it back. You can use transform

Comment: @Joe Ferndz, Well, it's true, but I prefer to use a dictionary to save some amount of memory.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right approach of doing it using groupby. However, groupby will only give you one row per group. To ensure you get the pd.Series of same length, you can use [transform](https://pbpython.com/pandas_transform.html).

With that, you can then compute the `'normalized'` value.

Here's the full code and sample rows of output:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
drinks = pd.read_csv('abc.txt')  #downloaded to my local copy
drinks['max_serving'] = drinks.groupby('continent')['beer_servings'].transform('max') 
drinks['normalized'] = drinks['beer_servings']/drinks['max_serving']
print (drinks[['country','beer_servings','continent','max_serving','normalized']].head(20))
```

Output of this will be:

```
              country  beer_servings      continent  max_serving  normalized
0         Afghanistan              0           Asia          247    0.000000
1             Albania             89         Europe          361    0.246537
2             Algeria             25         Africa          376    0.066489
3             Andorra            245         Europe          361    0.678670
4              Angola            217         Africa          376    0.577128
5   Antigua & Barbuda            102  North America          285    0.357895
6           Argentina            193  South America          333    0.579580
7             Armenia             21         Europe          361    0.058172
8           Australia            261        Oceania          306    0.852941
9             Austria            279         Europe          361    0.772853
10         Azerbaijan             21         Europe          361    0.058172
11            Bahamas            122  North America          285    0.428070
12            Bahrain             42           Asia          247    0.170040
13         Bangladesh              0           Asia          247    0.000000
14           Barbados            143  North America          285    0.501754
15            Belarus            142         Europe          361    0.393352
16            Belgium            295         Europe          361    0.817175
17             Belize            263  North America          285    0.922807
18              Benin             34         Africa          376    0.090426
19             Bhutan             23           Asia          247    0.093117
```

Comment: Interesting to see `Afghanistan` with 0 beer_servings :). As an example, in Europe, `Czech Republic` has 361. and thats how the number is picked. The computation is beer_serving / 361 for Europe only. So Belgium with 142/361=0.39